# NextJS typeRoutes and Generics

Tags: typescript, generics, next.js13

We've turned on the experimental `typedRoutes` in NextJS:

```
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  experimental: {
    typedRoutes: true,
  },
};
```

All this works well. I've even managed to make components accept type-checked URLS:

```
function InfoSection<T extends string>({
  editHref
}: {
  editHref: Route<T>;
}) {
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <Link href={editHref}>Edit</Link>
    ...
  );
}
```

However, I clearly don't understand TypeScript generics well enough. Why does *this* not work?

```
function test<T extends string>(companySlug: string): Route<T> {
  return `/profile/${companySlug}/company-details`;
}
```

I'm told that **Type '/profile/${string}/company-details' is not assignable to type 'Route'**. I gather that because it's a template string it's a little different, but I'm at a loss...